# Meteor call inside cursor.map throws error

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a meteor call "Send to all" inside another meteor call and cursor.map which throws error on server side but runs fine on client side below is the error: how do i remove this error ? meteor 1.8 react 16.8

```
 send all numbers error2 { Error: Method 'Send to all' not found [404]
I20190720-13:08:56.527(5.5)?     at Server.applyAsync (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1648:9)
I20190720-13:08:56.528(5.5)?     at Server.apply (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1625:26)
I20190720-13:08:56.529(5.5)?     at Server.call (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1607:17)
I20190720-13:08:56.530(5.5)?     at Find all numbers.userKisandb.find.fetch.map.Mob (imports/api/userKisan.js:47:24)
I20190720-13:08:56.531(5.5)?     at Array.map (<anonymous>)
I20190720-13:08:56.531(5.5)?     at MethodInvocation.Find all numbers (imports/api/userKisan.js:44:21)
I20190720-13:08:56.532(5.5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1771:12)
I20190720-13:08:56.533(5.5)?     at DDP._CurrentMethodInvocation.withValue (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:719:19)
I20190720-13:08:56.533(5.5)?     at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages\meteor.js:1234:12)
I20190720-13:08:56.534(5.5)?     at DDPServer._CurrentWriteFence.withValue (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:717:46)
I20190720-13:08:56.536(5.5)?     at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages\meteor.js:1234:12)
I20190720-13:08:56.537(5.5)?     at Promise (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:715:46)
I20190720-13:08:56.539(5.5)?     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
I20190720-13:08:56.539(5.5)?     at Session.method (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:689:23)
I20190720-13:08:56.540(5.5)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:559:43
I20190720-13:08:56.541(5.5)?   isClientSafe: true,
I20190720-13:08:56.542(5.5)?   error: 404,
I20190720-13:08:56.542(5.5)?   reason: 'Method \'Send to all\' not found',
I20190720-13:08:56.544(5.5)?   details: undefined,
I20190720-13:08:56.544(5.5)?   message: 'Method \'Send to all\' not found [404]',
I20190720-13:08:56.545(5.5)?   errorType: 'Meteor.Error' }

'Find all numbers' (smsText) {
        if(!this.userId) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
         }
          return userKisandb.find({
            userId: this.userId
         }).fetch().map((Mob) => {
            // return Mob.Mnumber
            if(Mob.Mnumber) {
                Meteor.call('Send to all',Mob.Mnumber,smsText,(err,resp) => {
                //this call throws error on server side
                  //sms.js
                  if(err){
                      console.log("send all numbers error2", err);
                    } else {
                      console.log("send all numbers sucess", resp);
                    }
              })
            }

         });
    },
```

And Method is

```
Meteor.methods({
  'Send to all'(mob,text) {
      let from = 1234;
      console.log(from);

  },
})
```

Comment: Did you import server side the file that contains the Meteor Method ?

Comment: thnx I haven't imported the file, now it is working,but why does it work on client side then

Comment: If it works on the client, it means you already imported it client side